# Comparator cannot be resolved to a type, what should i do

Tags: java

i want to use built in compare function to sort Strings according to specific method, but there was an error occurred. what should i use Comparator

VsCode
openjdk version "1.8.0_191-1-redhat"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-1-redhat-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

```
public String[] reorderLogFiles(String[] logs){

    Comparator<String> myComp = new Comparator<String>(){
        //@Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2){
            int s1si = s1.indexOf(' ');
            int s2si = s2.indexOf(' ');
            char s1fc = s1.charAt(s1si+1);
            char s2fc = s2.charAt(s2si+1);
            if(s1fc<='9'){
                if(s2fc<='9')return 0;
                else return 1;
            }
            if(s2fc<='9')return -1;

            int isNeedChange = s1.substring(s1si+1).compareTo(s2.substring(s2si+1));
            if(isNeedChange == 0)return s1.substring(0,s1si).compareTo(s2.substring(0,s2si));
            return isNeedChange;
        }
    };

    Arrays.sort(logs,myComp);
    return logs;
}
```

Comparator cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: if @override isn't noted, there was another error message:  The method compare(String, String) of type new Comparator<String>(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: have you imported it?

Comment: what message? that it wasn't overriding anything?  the compare method takes two instances of Object, not of String.

Comment: i find i forget import java.util.Comparator;   but why vscode didn't show me the problem or import it automatically?

Comment: what is vscode? and why would you want it to be all done 'automatically'. There may be thousands of classes called Comparator out there, do you want your code to choose for itself which one to use?

Comment: @Stultuske I think "vscode" is probably [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, i didn't consider it correctly (T T) and i should let code know the exact class i want to use. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the comparator API?

If not, Is your project on the build path? Maybe you have to configure your build path by making the src as source folder so that VsCode will prompt you to import Comparator.

Comment: the OP already stated in the comments he forgot the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible fixes:

## 1. Import the Comparator library

Add this to the top of your file:

`import java.util.Comparator;`

## 2. Incorrect Java Path

VS Code may be looking at a jre instead of a JDK.

How to fix:

1. hit `ctrl + shift + p` to bring up the command palette.
2. Type `>Java: Configure Java Runtime` and hit `enter`
3. Change the path to point to your JDK location. The default location is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkX.X.X_XXX`

[image: VS Code Java configuration]